# In CO (Colorado Office?)

Tags: abbreviations

Does "CO" stand for "Colorado Office"? Or just "Colorado"?

> Rebecca Ballhaus tweeted:
>
> *Jenna Ellis has said she is a former **Colorado** prosecutor and State Dept attorney. **In CO**, she handled traffic cases. She isn’t listed in State Dept payroll records & was listed in one 2013 case as a lawyer for a firm providing legal-discovery help to State.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For America states it is common to abbreviate to a 2 letter code. For Colorado, this is CO. So it just stands for Colorado here.

See [here](https://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/articles/state-abbrev.html) for the full list.